# How to learn and understand Quran without any prior Arabic or Urdu knowledge?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, arabic

Assalaamoalaikum,

I was going through some `youtube` series which aimed at `Arabic-grammar` teaching for the soul purpose of understanding **`Quran`**.

But after a couple of videos the instructor started handing out exercises for revision and application of the theory he was teaching. There were quite a number of words of Arabic language which completely went over my head.He translated some of them but it was not enough for an amateur like me. It put me quite in doubt as to how to cover all this `Arabic vocab` in order to understand their meaning.

Without the proper meaning of the words used it seems quite difficult to achieve my goal.

Anyone who can lend a hand here, I would be highly obliged.

All and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can have a copy of the Quran with Arabic and English translation so it can help you learn verses and their exact meaning.

Comment: Everyone knows that english can never reach the depths as compared to the arabic grammar used in **Quran**. The complete satisfaction can only be achieved if you really understand the language. I need to learn arabic to know the roots of the `holy book`.

Comment: Yes, it seems so since english is the only language that can act as a barrier from here to there.

Answer (score 0):

**Al-Quran is like a diamond, sparkling from anywhere.**

In the past, I started collecting my favorite verses. It's like my favorite quote. Then I began to search for its meaning and interpretation. And also Asbabun Nuzul, the cause of the revealed verses of Al-Quran. One by one.

That way I can understand a little Arabic.

In my opinion, to understand it, we must like it first.
:)

Comment: Brother, the likeness is to an extent which i cannot explain to in words. I do not want to memorize some verses only to quote or anything. I want to read and understand it for myself. Hope you can understand and do not take this in a negative way.

I need a source or some way to do understand and learn `quranic-arabic` .

Comment: Thank you for giving it time. Your help is greatly appreciated.